# Image mask for overlay not working on Motorola Xoom (android 4.0.4)

Tags: android, css

I was testing our web site and discovered that in android 4.0.4, the images are no longer masked properly.

Since there isn't a mask applied to the popup image, it's covered by a dark background.

This appears to be the related CSS code, which gets triggered from a "view larger" link. Any help trouble shooting this would be greatly appreciated:

```
 .overlay {
  background:none;
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:9999999;
  text-align:left;
  font-size:11px;
  color:#565656;
  font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000;
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 10px #000;
  }

.overlay #close-overlay {
width:62px;
height:30px;
cursor:pointer;
position:absolute;
background: url(../wwwasmeorg/media/images/button-close-overlay.gif) 10px 0px no-repeat #000;
font-size:12px;
color:#fff;
top:-30px;
right:0px;
line-height:30px;
padding-left:40px;
    }

   .overlay #overlay-img {
   }

   .overlay .caption {
padding:10px 0px;
color:#fff;
opacity:.8;
font-size:13px;
background:#242424; 
    }

   .overlay .caption p {
padding:0 7px;  
   }

   .overlay .cart-overlay {
background:#fff;
float:left;
padding:35px 40px 40px 40px;
width:380px;
font-size:16px;
line-height:21px;
text-align:center;
    }

   .overlay .cart-overlay .buttons {
margin-left:40px;
_margin-left:20px;
margin-top:30px;
    }

   .overlay .cart-overlay .buttons .blue-button {
margin-right:15px;  
    }

   .overlay .cart-overlay.error .buttons .blue-button {
margin-left:120px;  
_margin-left:60px;
    }

   .overlay .cart-overlay .buttons .green-button {
margin-top:-4px;
    }

    #overlay-landing.overlay {
    background:#000;
    opacity:.6;
    }

    #overlay-blocker {
    background:#000000;
    left:0;
    opacity:0.7;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    z-index:999999;
    }

    #overlay-blocker iframe {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    filter : alpha(opacity = 0);
    z-index: 9999;
    }

    #overlay-blocker {
    filter: alpha(opacity = 70);
    }

    #overlay-blocker #overlay-loading {
background:url(../wwwasmeorg/media/images/ajax-loader.gif) 0px 0px no-repeat;
height:16px;
width:16px;
position:absolute;  
    }

    #overlay-content {
    position:relative;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that Android 4.0.4 has poor support for CSS3 Image Masks. You may not have a problem in your CSS at all.